# Issue while installing sonarqube8.6.0.39681

Tags: java, c#, jvm, sonarqube, sonarlint

i have installed openjdk 15.0.1 and added the path in wrapper file and trying to run startsonar.bat file but getting this below response in console[image]

Comment: Text is better as text.

Answer (score 0):

Elastic search does not start, due to the use of a gc that is no longer supported in jvm: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/51361

Check for a solution here: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/51361#issuecomment-726177271

Update jvm.options file